# adding a document library to a site definition

Tags: 2010, site-definition

Ive created a custom list definition that inherits from document and i want to add it to my site definition. Ive included the feature in the site definition so its available but im not sure how to add it to my site definition so the library is actually created.  Do i simply add it to the lists section of the site definition and if so how can i get it to show under the documents library when viewing all site content

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a Web Template instead.

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/06/15/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx